# Escape exclamation mark in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I got a simple code to connect to remote server.
For some reason, it keep asking for password even when i already gave it in the code.
The password include exclamation mark, tried to escape it with \ / " " ' ' but none of them helped me.

The code:

```bat
    @echo off
    
    cmdkey /generic:server /user:user /pass:'Aa123456!' 
    mstsc.exe /v:server
    
    exit
```

Didn't gave the real server and user of course, but thats the password im using.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Is your password literally `'Aa123456!'` (with the starting and ending single quotes)? The character `'` is not special to `cmd.exe`. You may want to try `/pass:Aa123456^!`.

Comment: thanks, but I already tried it.

Answer (score 2):

The below batch log in to remote desktop using the credentials provided.

*Save* it as **RDPLogin.bat** *(edit credentials as required)*

use **^** for escape characters *(for example)*

```bat
@echo off
::Server Address/IP
set mysrvad=xyz.myrdp.com
::Server User ID
set mysrvid=user
::Server User Password
set mysrvpswd='Aa123456^!'

cmdkey /generic:%mysrvad% /user:%mysrvid% /pass:%mysrvpswd%
cls
mstsc.exe /v:%mysrvad%
exit
```

Comment: I tried you suggestion, it asked me again for my credential.
It's also said :
 "CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Default to Windows directory.
CMDKEY: Creddential added successfully." 

Is it relevant to my problem?

Comment: Does it open your rdp or not after it shows *Creddential added successfully*..?

i assume your login process problem should have been resolved using special character.

The only thing you would be seeing is the error message in prompt.

**`CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories`**

its windows `cmd` limitation error you can bypass it adding `CLS` below `cmdkey` command

Comment: It doesn't open the rdp. It's just ask for my password.
When i enter the same password again, I can log in like it should do.

Maybe be I am missing something? I used the code you gave me even though it's look just like mine but with comments.

And one more thing, could it be that my user name is wrong? the UNC PATH got me thinking.