# Mstsc command to login to remote machine with credentials

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rdp, mstsc

I am currently trying to create a batch file to navigate to a remote machine (from a given url) and enter credentials so I can start up my selenium grid quickly.

The following command brings up the prompt and enters the given ip into the address, however it asks for credentials to move on from there:

```
mstsc /v:IPADDRESS
```

I have tried to use the following command to specify username and password but it does not work:

```
    mstsc /v:IPADDRESS /user:USERNAME /pass:PASSWORD
```

I have also ticked the remember credentials option however my company admin does not allow the use of saved credentials because of identity verification purposes. I can't seem to find any solution based on what I've researched on Stack Overflow.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: similar question check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47324630/8906305